# Generating images from an array of categories

Tags: conditional-content

I'm using the following code to display images based on the category id:

```
<?php 
if (is_category( 'web-design' )){
?>   
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider_webdesign.png" title="خدمات تصميم وتطوير المواقع" height="200px" width="960px" />
<?php
}else if (is_category( 'printing' )){
?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider_printing.png" title="تصميم مطبوعات" height="200px" width="960px" />
<?php
}else if (is_category( 'online-marketing' )){
?>
```

I would like to make an array of only one condition to display an image with the category slug, is that possible?

Comment: FYI, `bloginfo('template_directory')` is deprecated. Recommended function now is `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_category()` takes an array as arguments if you want to check for more than one category. But you can make it even easier with a check for existing files:

```
if ( is_category() )
{
    $slug       = get_queried_object()->slug;
    $theme_path = "/images/slider_$slug.png";
    $file       = get_template_directory() . $theme_path;

    if ( file_exists( $file ) )
    {
        echo '<img src="' 
            . get_template_directory_uri() . $theme_path 
            . '" alt="" height="200px" width="960px" />';
    }
}
```